# Merge two XMLs with common fields and adding fields from both xmls using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have two xmls

1. `a.xml`
2. `b.xml`

Below is the `a.xml` file

```
<proj_details>
    <proj_detail>
        <Username>Username</Username>
        <ID>ID</ID>
        <Place>Ocean</Place>
        <City>Urban</City>
        <!-- some more fields -->
    </proj_detail>
    <proj_detail>
        <Username>abc@abc.com</Username>
        <ID>QoChiX5FlqU7VB2MKw5Aa</ID>
        <Place>Road</Place>
        <City>Rural</City>
        <!-- some more fields -->
    </proj_detail>
    <proj_detail>
        <Username>abc@abc.com</Username>
        <ID>uzGjRVxnZPtB9sfiXtga</ID>
        <Place>Mud</Place>
        <City>SemiRural</City>
        <!-- some more fields -->
    </proj_detail>
    <proj_detail>
        <Username>abc@abc.com</Username>
        <ID>YChiX5FluqhuyVB2OPw5Aa</ID>
        <Place>Sea</Place>
        <City>Sealine</City>
        <!-- some more fields -->
    </proj_detail>
    <proj_detail>
        <Username>abc@abc.com</Username>
        <ID>RD37oO2jgW5p6f76W8up</ID>
        <Place>Lane</Place>
        <City>Leftsidelane</City>
        <!-- some more fields -->
    </proj_detail>
    </proj_details>

    <!-- more fields    -->
```

and below is the b.xml

```
    <FilebDetail>
        <Number>34</Number>
        <CONS>abc@abc.com</CONS>
        <PROD>xyz@xyz.com</PROD>
        <ID>QoChiX5FlqU7VB2MKw5Aa</ID>
        <Name>Directory/notepad</Name>
        <Count>43</Count>
        <time>43550.53333336</time>
        <!-- some more fields-->
    </FilebDetail>
    <FilebDetail>
        <Number>35</Number>
        <CONS>abc@abc.com</CONS>
        <PROD>cvb@cvb.com</PROD>
        <ID>uzGjRVxnZPtB9sfiXtga</ID>
        <Name>Speed/morning</Name>
        <Count>42</Count>
        <time>43550.5778</time>
        <!-- some more fields-->
    </FilebDetail>
    <FilebDetail>
        <Number>31</Number>
        <CONS>abc@abc.com</CONS>
        <PROD>cvb@cvb.com</PROD>
        <ID>RD37oO2jgW5p6f76W8up</ID>
        <Name>Weatherincity</Name>
        <Count>12</Count>
        <time>43550.498611111114</time>
        <!-- some more fields-->
    </FilebDetail>

    </FilebDetails>
```

Now, I want to get the output somewhat like below

```
        <proj_detail>
        <Number>34</Number>
        <CONS>abc@abc.com</CONS>
        <PROD>xyz@xyz.com</PROD>
        <ID>QoChiX5FlNyqe1FuqU7VB2M</ID>
        <Name>Directory/notepad</Name>
        <Count>12</Count>
        <time>43550.498611111114</time>
        <Place>Road</Place>
        <City>Rural</City>
         <!-- some more fields -->
        </proj_detail>

        <proj_detail>
        <Number>35</Number>
        <CONS>abc@abc.com</CONS>
        <PROD>cvb@cvb.com</PROD>
        <ID>uzGjRVxnxmP00zrnZPtB9sM</ID>
        <Name>Speed/morning</Name>
        <Count>42</Count>
        <time>43550.5778</time>
        <Place>Mud</Place>
        <City>SemiRural</City>
        </proj_detail>
         <!-- some more fields -->
        <proj_detail>
        <Number>31</Number>
        <CONS>abc@abc.com</CONS>
        <PROD>cvb@cvb.com</PROD>
        <ID>RD37oO2jg4rlerxW5p6f76</ID>
        <Name>Weatherincity</Name>
        <Count>12</Count>
        <time>43550.498611111114</time>
        <Place>Lane</Place>
        <City>Leftsidelane</City>
        </proj_detail>
        <!-- some more fields -->
        </proj_details>
```

In both files ID is common and that is what needs to be compared. Once its compared, then we the corresponding fields from both the files are to be printed.

I am pretty new in xslt. Any xslt version would be ok to use.

Any guidance in this would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a one-to-one relationship, the merging will be straightforward. Running this XSLT 2.0 stylesheet with `a.xml` as input and `b.xml` as parameter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:param name="update"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="proj_detail">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
              select="$update/FilebDetails/FilebDetail[ID = current()/ID]/(* except ID)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note:** You have to be careful about the mechanism your XSLT processor has for passing nodes as parameters, otherwise you will need to use the `document()` function.

From this basic transformation you can add optimizations like the use of `key()` function (you will have to use the XSLT 2.0 -arity 3- `key()` function). Also you could declare that key by `ID` and "field" name assuming that `$update` parameter is an update stream and thus you will be selecting the last ones, etc.

Comment: @2437850 And why do think that?